# Does it make sense to have multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinators?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm new to Core Data, and I'm trying to make sure that I've got my data model and its usage set up properly.

I basically have two file types in my App ... one contains settings type data and a second contains data sets that the user will be working with (kind of like documents, although I can imagine the user working across 10s or even 100s of these files simultaneously).

I've been reading books on Core Data, and I remember reading that typically an app has a single `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, a single `NSManagedObjectContext` and a single `NSManagedObjectModel`.

I currently have a single managed object model with configurations for the various file types I have. I had been planning on also having one of the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinators` / `NSManagedObjectContexts`, and when I create new Core Data objects, I would make sure that each one was added to the correct persistent store.

However, I've seen examples where each file has its own `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Are there advantages and disadvantages to having multiple `NSPersistentStoreCoordinators` and `NSManagedObjectContexts` in a single thread application?

Initially, I had been hoping to be able to move objects from one persistent store to another during user cut and paste type edits, but that doesn't seem possible either way.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

Here is some more information about what is confusing me. When I read the documentation about NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, it says:

> The coordinator is designed to present
>   a façade to the managed object
>   contexts such that a group of
>   persistent stores appears as an
>   aggregate store.

In my case, this is not what I want. I want my documents to be perceived as separate documents, and I don't want the queries to be confused between each other.

In addition, with only one persistent store coordinator and many persistent stores, if I forget to assign an entity to the correct store on creation, I find myself with bugs since entities are arbitrarily assigned to a valid store when they are created. I'm not sure what would happen with relationships that point to objects in different stores (probably an assertion failure?).

To me, it seems that having a single context / persistent store coordinator per store would be less prone to bugs, and allows me to keep the data for each document isolated from each other.

The only thing that a single persistent store seems to buy me is that I can perform a save operation for all stores simultaneously which would be preferable. With multiple contexts / store coordinators, I would need to perform separate save operations.

If you use the OSX NSPersistentDocument class, it seems to enforce a separate context / store coordinator per document.

Anyway, from all my research, it seems that separate store coordinators / contexts would work better for my App, but the reason I posted this is because I am new to Core Data and this approach does seem to go against the recommended flow and I'm worried that I'm missing some gotchas that will come back to bite me.

**More Thoughts / Information**

As I think about this more and read more feedback from others (thank you everyone!!!), my current thoughts are as follows.

For myself, there really doesn't seem to be that much difference between the two approaches and I currently believe that I could make it work well either way.

With a single store coordinator, I need to make sure that newly created entities are attached to the correct store (not really a big deal). With multiple store coordinators, I need to make sure that newly created entities are added to the correct context (of which I will have many of them). With the way my code is structured, either approach should be relatively easy for me.

I personally want to search a single store at a time. If I have multiple store coordinators, this is automatic. If I have a single store coordinator, I need to make sure to constrain the fetch request. (either way, not really a big deal).

The documentation for the store coordinator implies that its advantage is making multiple stores appear as one. For my app, I do not need or want that so this is not really a consideration for me (although if I wanted to add cross-store searching capabilities in the future, it would be best to keep everything in a single store coordinator).

To me, none of the above reasons are really good arguments either way, and if they were the only arguments, I would probably try to do things the more conventional way and stick with a single store coordinator.

However, one final reason (and the main reason that I originally posted this question) is that I am planning on taking advantage of some features in iOS 5 that seem to require multiple store coordinators. I want to be able to weak-link my app to be backwards compatible, so it seems that having my iOS 4 code closely resemble the iOS 5 code would be preferable.

The more I think about this, with the support for multiple OS versions, I could probably still implement things either way with the correct abstractions.

Thank you everyone for your feedback! I'm slowly getting the hang of Core Data which has mostly been a great experience, although its given me my share of headaches as well!

Comment: if you can "refactor" your question to be more general (ie, not about iOS 5), then you'll hopefully get an answer.  Until then, as @Caleb mentions, iOS 5 is under NDA and we won't answer this.  If you need to know about how this works in iOS 5, please ask the question on http://devforums.apple.com.

Comment: You are both right ... I re-worded my question (my question didn't really have anything to do with iOS 5 anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Generally an app will use only one PersistentStoreCoordinator and it is initialized in app delegate.

For more details and clarification please check the apples doc on [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the docs. However, I have read through the entire documentation. I have also read through Marcus Zarra's "Core Data" book as well as "Pro Core Data for iOS" by Michael Privat / Robert Warner. They are all good books, although they still don't answer my questions above. I've read that an App should only have one PersistentStoreCoordinator, although I'm still not sure that it is best for my needs. See my clarifications above.

Answer (score 2):

I can't honestly think of a reason why you would want to have a second coordinator unless you are performing some pretty serious concurrent, multi threaded tasks on the same model. From what you described above, you may only need to create a separate context for certain managed objects, or possibly separate stores if you need them to be completely independent.

You will hardly ever interact directly with a persistent store coordinator as most of your operations are done on the context level and then persisted when you are ready (again via context) through the store coordinator.

You've obviously done your own research so I am not going to tell you to check documentation XYZ (Core Data is well documented for basic level stuff but anything slightly more advanced and you are on your own), but my main point is that having a separate store coordinator for each of these models will probably increase the complexity of your code instead of making it easier to manage which seems to be your main motivation in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real technical limitation to having multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instances in your app as long as they are all pointed to a unique location on disk.

However, taking that approach is definitely not common and is going to add a lot of complexity to your app that may not be necessary.  From what you've described about your data model, I don't see any reason why you'd need multiple NSPersistentStoreCoordinators.

Be sure to read the CoreData Programming Guide and know that you'll need to create a unique NSManagedObjectContext per thread, rather than per NSPersistentStoreCoordinator as you described in your question.

Comment: Paul ... thanks for the comments! I'm just a little confused about your comment about needing a single context per thread. If I have multiple store coordinators, don't I need multiple contexts as well? Also, I'm not sure why doing what I said above would add complexity? In some ways (see my edit above), it seems to reduce complexity to me (I don't have to worry about making sure that entities are created in the correct stores, and how to restrict queries to pull in only entites from the store I am trying to search).

Comment: Yes, sorry if my phrasing was confusing. If you have multiple NSPSC's (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's) you would need a NSMOC per NSPSC and per thread in your app.  This adds complexity in that you'd need to to be careful to structure your app, such that you can be sure you're always writing to/reading from the right store and context. I'm also confused why you're worried about having separate stores per document/entity.  With a well-thought-out data model, this shouldn't be an issue.  Is there anything else you could share about what led you to feeling you need that?

Comment: Paul ... thanks again for the insights! I'm not too worried about the complexity of managing the stores and contexts as my files are wrapped in their own class which will manage all of the creation and deletion of objects. I just added some more thoughts above which will hopefully explain my reasoning a little more.